# Asp.net no devuelve las vistas

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, routing

¡Hola a todos!

Estoy creando una app de asp.net, en donde cree tres vistas razor pages: Create, Edit y Details. Mi directorio del proyecto se estructura de la siguiente manera:

```
--App
----Models/
----Controller/
----Views/
------Subject/
---------Create.cshtml
---------Edit.cshtml
---------Delete.cshtml
---------Details.cshtml
```

Explico:

Este es mi `SubjectControllers.cs` que es el controlador predeterminado para el manejo de Subjects:

```
using AspNetCorePostgreSQLDockerApp.Repository;
using AspNetCorePostgreSQLDockerApp.Models;

namespace net_core_app.Controllers
{
    public class SubjectController : Controller
    {
        private readonly SubjectDbContext _context;

        public SubjectController(SubjectDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Subject
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
              if( _context.Subject != null)
                 {
                    return  View(await _context.Subject.ToListAsync());
                 } else {
                     return Problem("Entity set 'netcoreapicontext.Subject'  is null.");
                 };
        }

        // GET: Subject/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Subject == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var subject = await _context.Subject
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.CourseID == id);
            if (subject == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(subject);
        }

        // GET: Subject/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Subject/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("CourseID,Title,Credits")] Subject subject)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(subject);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(subject);
        }

        // GET: Subject/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Subject == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var subject = await _context.Subject.FindAsync(id);
            if (subject == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(subject);
        }

        // POST: Subject/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id, [Bind("CourseID,Title,Credits")] Subject subject)
        {
            if (id != subject.CourseID)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(subject);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!SubjectExists(subject.CourseID))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(subject);
        }

        // GET: Subject/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Subject == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var subject = await _context.Subject
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.CourseID == id);
            if (subject == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(subject);
        }

        // POST: Subject/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int? id)
        {
            if (_context.Subject == null)
            {
                return Problem("Entity set 'netcoreapicontext.Subject'  is null.");
            }
            var subject = await _context.Subject.FindAsync(id);
            if (subject != null)
            {
                _context.Subject.Remove(subject);
            }
            
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        private bool SubjectExists(int? id)
        {
          return (_context.Subject?.Any(e => e.CourseID == id)).GetValueOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Y este son mis vistas:

```
 Edit.cshtml

@model AspNetCorePostgreSQLDockerApp.Models.Subject


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}
<h2>Editar</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Materia</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CourseID)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Credits, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Credits)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Credits)
            </div>
        </div>
        @*Genre and Price removed for brevity.*@        
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Volver a inicio", "Details")
</div>

Details.cshtml

@model IEnumerable<AspNetCorePostgreSQLDockerApp.Models.Subject>;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Credits)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Credits)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.CourseID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.CourseID  }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.CourseID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Pero cuando trato de acceder a una de las vistas colocando la ruta predeterminada colocando la ruta: `http://localhost:5000/Subject/Edit/5` tratando de acceder a la vista Edit no se redirecciona sino que se queda en la misma pagina.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aca esta el endpoint predeterminado en `Startup.cs`

```
  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");

                // Handle redirecting client-side routes to Customers/Index route
                endpoints.MapFallbackToController("Index", "Customers");
            });
```

Creo que es un problema de mal uso de ViewData ya que creo que no pasa informacion correctamente del controlador a la vista, pero de todos modos deberia redireccionarse. Si me podrian ayudar a acceder a las vistas de Asp.net estaria agradecido.